# Best possible way for checking if an array of dates consist of n number of consecutive days or not in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of stringified dates like,

```
arr = ["9-7-2020", "11-7-2020", "12-7-2020", "10-7-2020", "16-7-2020", "15-7-2020", "19-7-2020"]
```

now I want to check if this array consist of atleast 3 consecutive dates, so what should be the best possible way to do it in node?

Comment: Please add the code you've tried

Comment: sort the array , then iterate and check the distance

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be this, where we get and sort the timestamps of each date, and then we can check for consecutive dates by subtracting a day's milliseconds multiplied by its index and checking if the same timestamp occurs more than or equal to N times.

```js
const arr = ["9-7-2020", "11-7-2020", "12-7-2020", "10-7-2020", "16-7-2020", "15-7-2020", "19-7-2020"];

const ONE_DAYS_MILLIS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

const hasNConsecutive = (dates, N) => {

    // Remove duplicate dates if any
    const uniqueDays = [... new Set(dates)];

    const dateOccurrences = uniqueDays
        .map((date) => date.split('-'))
        // Get a timestamp for each date
        .map(([day, month, year]) => new Date(year, month, day).getTime())
        .sort()
        // Since we have sorted the timestamps we can now check for
        // consecutive dates by subtracting a day multiplied 
        // by the index and checking if the same timestamp
        // occurs more than or equal to N times
        .map((ts, index) => ts - index * ONE_DAYS_MILLIS)
        .reduce((count, ts) => {
            
            count[ts] = (count[ts] || 0) + 1;
            
            return count;
        },
        {});

    return Object.values(dateOccurrences).some((times) => times >= N);
};

const result = hasNConsecutive(arr, 3);

console.log(result);
```

Or if you are using `lodash` you can do the same thing a little bit easier.

```js
const arr = ["9-7-2020", "11-7-2020", "12-7-2020", "10-7-2020", "16-7-2020", "15-7-2020", "19-7-2020"];

const ONE_DAYS_MILLIS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

const result = _
    .chain(arr)
    .uniq()
    .map((date) => date.split('-'))
    .map(([day, month, year]) => new Date(year, month, day).getTime())
    .sort()
    .map((ts, index) => ts - index * ONE_DAYS_MILLIS)
    .countBy(_.identity)
    .values()
    .some((count) => count >= 3)
    .value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.19/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could crate `Date` objects from those date string, sort them and then go through the array and check if the previous date plus one day is equal to the current date and keep a count of how many times that condition is true in a row.

Here is an example:

```js
const arr = ["9-7-2020", "11-7-2020", "12-7-2020", "10-7-2020", "16-7-2020", "15-7-2020", "19-7-2020"]
const requiredConsecutiveCount = 3;
const getDate = (dateStr) => new Date(dateStr.split("-").reverse().map(v => parseInt(v)).map((v, i) => i === 1 ? (v + 1) : v));

const hasConsecutive = arr.map(getDate)
  .sort((a, b) => a.getTime() - b.getTime())
  .some(function(v, i, arr) {
    if (i > 0) {
      const tmp = new Date(arr[i - 1]);
      tmp.setDate(tmp.getDate() + 1);
      if (tmp.getTime() === v.getTime()) {
        this.consecutiveCount++;
      } else {
        this.consecutiveCount = 0;
      }
    }
    return this.consecutiveCount === requiredConsecutiveCount;
  }, {
    consecutiveCount: 0
  });
console.log(hasConsecutive);
```

Probably my way of converting from a string date to a `Date` object is more complex than it has to be.

Answer (score 0):

Two things needed here:

1. Sort the array by date, probably need to convert dates along the way
2. Then check if date diff to next element is 1 day *and* date diff to the element after that is 2 days

```
var arr = ["9-7-2020", "11-7-2020", "12-7-2020", "10-7-2020", "16-7-2020", "15-7-2020", "19-7-2020"]

var ONE_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

function hasNConsecutive(arr, numConsecutive){
  // new Date() is locale dependent. You might need to modify this heavily if you need to be locale-agnostic 
  var dateArray = arr.map(function(d){return new Date(d).getTime()}).sort();

  var consecutiveCount = 1;

  for(var i=1; i<dateArray.length; i++) {
    if(dateArray[i] - dateArray[i-1] != ONE_DAY) {
      consecutiveCount = 1;
      continue;
    }
  
    consecutiveCount++;
  
    if(consecutiveCount == numConsecutive) return true;
  }

  return false;
}

console.log(hasNConsecutive(arr, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

what's happening here is, we are making the month or the day a two digit if it isn't one, then we are constructing integer which has value like this "YYYYMMDD" then we are subtracting from three times of the first day with sum of three consecutive days, answer will be three if they are consecutive days
(caution: **no duplicate dates must exist**)

```js
var arr = ["9-7-2020", "11-7-2020", "12-7-2020", "10-7-2020", "16-7-2020", "15-7-2020", "19-7-2020"]

arr.map((v) => (v.split("-").map((val) => (val.length == 1 ? "0" + val : val)).reverse().join(""))).map((value) => (parseInt(value))).sort((a, b) => (a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0)).forEach((v, i, arr2) => {
  if (i + 2 < arr2.length) {
    var three = (v + arr2[i + 1] + arr2[i + 2]) - (v * 3)
    if (three == 3) console.log('three consecutive days')
  }
})
```